# Access violation reading location 0x00184000

Tags: c++, c, directx

having troubles with the following line

```
HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &mVB));
```

it appears the CreateBuffer method is having troubles reading &mVB. mVB is defined in box.h and looks like this

```
ID3D10Buffer* mVB;
```

Below is the code it its entirety. this is all files that mVB is in.

```
//Box.cpp
#include "Box.h"
#include "Vertex.h"
#include <vector>

Box::Box()
: mNumVertices(0), mNumFaces(0), md3dDevice(0), mVB(0), mIB(0)
{   
}

Box::~Box()
{
    ReleaseCOM(mVB);
    ReleaseCOM(mIB);
}

float Box::getHeight(float x, float z)const
{
    return 0.3f*(z*sinf(0.1f*x) + x*cosf(0.1f*z));
}

void Box::init(ID3D10Device* device, float m, float n, float dx)
{
    md3dDevice = device;
    mNumVertices = m*n;
    mNumFaces = 12;

    float halfWidth = (n-1)*dx*0.5f;
    float halfDepth = (m-1)*dx*0.5f;
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices(mNumVertices);

    for(DWORD i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        float z = halfDepth - (i * dx);
        for(DWORD j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            float x = -halfWidth + (j* dx);

            float y = getHeight(x,z);

            vertices[i*n+j].pos = D3DXVECTOR3(x, y, z);

            if(y < -10.0f)
                vertices[i*n+j].color = BEACH_SAND;
            else if( y < 5.0f)
                vertices[i*n+j].color = LIGHT_YELLOW_GREEN;
            else if (y < 12.0f)
                vertices[i*n+j].color = DARK_YELLOW_GREEN;
            else if (y < 20.0f)
                vertices[i*n+j].color = DARKBROWN;
            else
                vertices[i*n+j].color = WHITE;
        }
    }

    D3D10_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
    vbd.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * mNumVertices;
    vbd.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
    D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
    vinitData.pSysMem = &vertices;
    HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &mVB));

    //create the index buffer 

    std::vector<DWORD> indices(mNumFaces*3); // 3 indices per face

    int k = 0;

    for(DWORD i = 0; i < m-1; ++i)
    {
        for(DWORD j = 0; j < n-1; ++j)
        {
            indices[k]      = i*n+j;
            indices[k+1]    = i*n+j+1;
            indices[k+2]    = (i*1)*n+j;

            indices[k+3]    = (i*1)*n+j;
            indices[k+4]    = i*n+j+1;
            indices[k+5]    = (i*1)*n+j+1;

            k+= 6;
        }
    }

    D3D10_BUFFER_DESC ibd;
    ibd.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * mNumFaces*3;
    ibd.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    ibd.MiscFlags = 0;
    D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;
    iinitData.pSysMem = &indices;
    HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&ibd, &iinitData, &mIB));
}

void Box::Draw()
{
    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    md3dDevice->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &mVB, &stride, &offset);
    md3dDevice->IASetIndexBuffer(mIB, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
    md3dDevice->DrawIndexed(mNumFaces*3, 0 , 0);

}


//Box.h

#ifndef _BOX_H
#define _BOX_H
#include "d3dUtil.h"
```

Box.h

```
class Box {
public:

    Box();
    ~Box();

    void  init(ID3D10Device* device, float m, float n, float dx);
    void  Draw();
    float getHeight(float x, float z)const;

private:
    DWORD mNumVertices;
    DWORD mNumFaces;

    ID3D10Device* md3dDevice;
    ID3D10Buffer* mVB;
    ID3D10Buffer* mIB;
};

#endif
```

[EDIT]
Arguements being passed for m and n dx is

m = 129, n = 129, dx = 1.0f (they are all floats)

m and n stand for rows and columns perspectively. dx is the width and height.

Thanks again for the help

Comment: What arguments do you give to `init()`?

Comment: Btw: I suppose your `box` is meant to be a cuboid, so why does it have `n*m` vertices? Shouldn't it have just 8 (and hence, 12 faces)?

Comment: n and m are I believe are the numbers of vertices in the x and z direction. multiplying them gives you the total amount. I think. this is code I am learning myself from a book by frank luna on directx 10. i updated the information

Comment: I suggest to simplify the example to the following, so you might have better insight in how it works:
 - set `mNumVertices = 8`, `mNumFaces = 12`, so that you have just a simple cube
 - replace the `vector` by an usual array (as sth pointed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pointer to the data array of a vector, you should use `&vec[0]`. If you use `&vec` it will give you a pointer to the vector object, which might contain all kinds management structures/... that have nothing to do with the data you inserted into the vector.

The data itself is stored at continuous memory starting at `&vec[0]`, so use that when you initialize your D3D structures.

Comment: I thought so as well, but do you think, that this will really cause an access violation? I think this might "just" give wrong values to the GPU.

Comment: @phimuemue: Not certain, but typically the vector object itself will be rather small, because all the inserted elements will be stored in some dynamically allocated place while the vector itself only contains a pointer to that. So reading lots of data from `&vec` will probably read past the end of the vector object and might (or might not) reach some addresses that are in fact not allocated at all and lead to an access violation.

Comment: I have another issue, but that fixed the first problem. I probably will just post another if I can't figure it out. But I did notice that the book took away the [0] and the code did have them.